# Delimeter not working, "Syntax" errors when running .sql from shell

Tags: mysql, shell, syntax, delimiter

I'm trying to make a simple stored procedure... After exploring a bit, I discover I can't make any procedure at all, not even the simplest.
For exemple, running this [specific](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) procedure from the documentation:

```
DELIMETER ;
DROP PORCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_dorepeat
DELIMETER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
END //
DELIMETER ;
```

Gives me the following error:
[image: pain]

***Which is basically the same syntax error on every line***.
Changing the $$ for // also doesn't have any effect, as suggested [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-delimiter/).

It's worth knowing that I'm running the shell as root, so there are no restrictions.
Is there anything wrong with my code? The database is mysql 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can , but with the right keywords

`DELIMETER` -> `DELIMITER`

`PORCEDURE` -> `PROCEDURE`

Comment: I've been trying this so late I didn't even notice lol, it was 7 a.m. Thx, my friend, I need to make a ton code and deliver tomorrow.